# How to move SVG line with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I don't know how to set the x1, y1, x2, y2 parameters in javascript from the SVG element.

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
    <line id="line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just

```
var line = document.getElementById("line");
line.setAttribute("x1", "5");
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var line = document.getElementById('line')
line.x1.baseVal.value = 5
```

Is one char shorter (three if counting noise) than the other answer.

Comment: it's more efficient too if you're doing this in a loop as there's only one string to float conversion (when the javascript is parsed), rather than one every time it's executed.

Comment: `setAttribute` can set numeric values, but it also updates the dynamic page source so it's probably slower.

Comment: No, set attribute takes a string which is then converted to a float when it's stored in the browser's DOM. With baseVal.value a float is directly sent by the javascript interpreter/JIT to the browser's DOM.

Comment: Then the DOM is not what Chrome's inspector shows; that doesn't update with `value =`.

Comment: It should do. Firefox does and it would be a bug in Chrome if it didn't.

Comment: Indeed; reopening the inspector does show the change by `=`.